# Lie algebra of a closed subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a closed connected subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$. Denote $\mathfrak{g} \subseteq \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb{R})$ its Lie algebra.

It is known that $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ if and only if $\exp(tX) \in G$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm wondering if it is true that $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ if and only if $\exp(X) \in G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X\in\mathfrak g$ then $\exp(X)\in G$. The converse is not true. For instance take
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2\pi \\ -2\pi & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $\exp(X)$ is the identity matrix, so it belongs to any closed connected subgroup $G$. However the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ does not necessarily contain $X$.